# Access denied error while installing application remotely using WMIC(Windows management Instrumentation Command line )

Tags: wmic

Access denied error while installing application remotely using WMIC(Windows management Instrumentation Command line )

While installing the application remotely using  WMIC(Windows management Instrumentation ). We are getting following "access denied" error.

**Syntax used:**

```
wmic:root\cli>/node:<computer-name or ipaddress> product call install true ,"","Path of .msi file in remote machine"
```

**example:**
    wmic:root\cli>/node:192.168.100.3 product call install true ,"","f:\Setup.msi"

```
But we getting following error:
```

> "ERROR:
>       Description = Access is denied."

**note:**
    we can access that machine using Remote Desktop Connection(RDP) and also we provided all administrative  privileges to that machine.But while using wmic it shows access denied description.